# renaming mongodb collection in yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I am trying to rename a mongodb collection in a yii application, how ever it's throwing an error:

> Exception 'yii\mongodb\Exception' with message 'renameCollection may
>   only be run against the admin database.'

So I have added the complete namespace but still no success.

```
 $command = Yii::$app->mongodb->createCommand([
                    'renameCollection' => MONGODB_DATABASE . '.interim_product',
                    'to' => MONGODB_DATABASE . '.temp_interim_product'
                ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says as the command must be run against the `admin` database namespace. Fortunately the [`createCommand()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/doc/api/2.1/yii-mongodb-connection#createCommand()-detail) method supports providing a database namespace to execute against at it's second option.

Just hardcoding the *namespace* for example purposes, but presuming your target database was called `test` then the fully qualified names with the "dot" `.` would be:

```
Yii::$app->createCommand(
  [ 'renameCollection' => 'test.interim_product', 'to' => 'test.temp_interim_product' ]
  'admin'
)
```

So really all that is required is to *"fully qualify"* the name of the collections in both cases of the *source* and the *to* name and specify the `admin` database as the namespace to actually execute the command from.

Note also that the user account connected must have sufficient privileges assigned in order to actually rename the collection. Being typically covered by the [`readWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWrite) role

Comment: Thank you @Neil, was missing the 'admin'  bit. Working code as follows
```
  Yii::$app->mongodb->createCommand([
                    'renameCollection' => MONGODB_DATABASE . '.interim_product',
                    'to' => MONGODB_DATABASE . '.temp_interim_product',
                    'dropTarget'=>true,
                ],'admin')->execute();
```